# How to pass input value after button clicked on modal in slack bolt?

Tags: typescript, slack, bolt

I'm trying to pass value of input box on modal after click "Submit".
But I don't know how to get the value. I've searched ack, body, client, payload but i couldn't find it.

I already registered shortcuts in slack API page too.

Also, I don't know how to close modal either. Can you help me?

Here's my code.

```
import { App, BlockAction, ButtonAction, InputBlock } from "@slack/bolt";

const app = new App({
  appToken: SLACK_APP_TOKEN,
  token: SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  socketMode: true
});

// ....

app.action('update-today-attendance', async ({ ack, body, client, payload }) => {
  await ack();

  const values = (<ButtonAction>(<BlockAction>body).actions[0]).value.split(' / ');

  const result = await client.views.open({
    trigger_id: (<BlockAction>body).trigger_id,
    view: {
      type: "modal",
      callback_id: 'update-today-attendance-button-clicked',
      title: {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "TITLE",
        "emoji": true
      },
      submit: {  // ⬅️ Here, Submit button
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit",
        "emoji": true
      },
      "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": true
      },
      blocks: [
        {
          "type": "input",  // ⬅️ Here is input!
          "element": {
            "type": "plain_text_input",
            "action_id": "plain_text_input-action",
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "memo",
            "emoji": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
});

app.view('update-today-attendance-button-clicked', async ({ ack, body, client, payload }) => {
  const userId = body.view.title.text.split(' - ')[1];

  const adminName = body.user.name;

  // ⬅️ Here, I want to get value of input

  const response = await axios.put(
    `${SERVER_URL}/today/${userId}`, 
    { adminName, memo: '????' }
  );  

  // ⬅️ Here, I want to close modal
})

app.start().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);

  process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modal will be closed automatically once you call `await ack()` in `app.view` subscription.
Just keep in mind that it should be done within 3 seconds after user submitted the modal.

And the data user provided should be found in `view.state.values`.
If it is empty, check whether the blocks of your modal are of type `input`.